# Confidence bands for model averaged predictions of GLMMs

Tags: glmm, information-theory, model-averaging

I use R with the MuMIn package for Multimodel inference.
My global Model is

```
M.global <- glmer(y ~ c1 + I(c1^2) + c2 + c3 + c4 + (1|subject),data, family =poisson(link="log))
```

After that I use

```
M.dredge <- dredge(M.global, m.max=3, subset = dc(cpl,I(cpl^2)))
```

To calculate all possible models from the global model and rank them by AICc. `m.max` limits the number of predictor to 3 and `dc` is a dependency chain, so the function takes the squared c1 only if unsquared c1 is included. `m.max` is used since the total sample size is 30, and according to Harrels 10:1 rule of thumb there is amximum of 3 predictors to avoid overfitting.

The I use

M.avg <- model.avg(M.dredge, subset= delta < 4, fit=TRUE))

to get the model average across a subset of candidate models with a maximum difference of 4 AICc points to the "best" model having the lowest AICc. `fit = TRUE` refits every model in the subset.

Now I can use `M.avg` to get the averaged (full and conditional) coefficients for all predictors included in the subset as well as for the confdidence intervals:

```
Coef <- coef(M.avg, full=TRUE)
CI <- confint(M.avg, full=TRUE)
```

**Now my question:** Using poisson GLMMs and model averaging, how can I calculate model predictions and according confidence intervals for these predictions, to be used in a graph showing the regression line and confidence bands for that line?

[Here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1420-9101.2010.02210.x/full#ss4) they fill in the coefficients in the Model formula by hand and calculate point estimates for a given value (0, and 0.25) for the predictor `f`. Afterwards they repeat the procedure with the lower and the upper value of the confidence interval for the coefficients. However, I repeated that and I got something like this:

[image]

Comment: how about `predict(se.fit = TRUE)`?

Comment: This causes the following error:  Error in predict.averaging(ls.avgModels[[1]], se.fit = TRUE) : 
  'predict' for models '21', '23', '29', '19', '17', '53', '31', '51', '49', '55', '61' and '63' caused errors
In addition: There were 12 warnings (use warnings() to see them)

Comment: And this is the Warning: 1: In predict.merMod(object = <S4 object of class structure("lmerMod", package = "lme4")>,  ... :
  cannot calculate predictions with both standard errors and random effects

Comment: `?predict.merMod` says: `re.form` argument - "if `NA` or `~0`, include no random effects."

Comment: Aaaaahhh Oh my god, I'm sorry I did not looked good enough in the help file. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Hi thanks to lots of hints by Kamil Bartón, i ended up with the following procedure:

```
M.global <- glmer(y ~ c1 + I(c1^2) + c2 + c3 + c4 + (1|subject),data, family =poisson(link="log))
M.dredge <- dredge(M.global, m.max=3, subset = dc(cpl,I(cpl^2)))
M.avg <- model.avg(M.dredge, subset= delta < 4, fit=TRUE))

newdata <- expand.grid(c1= with(data, seq(min(c1), max(c1), length.out=50)),
                       c2 = mean(data$c2),
                       c3 = mean(data$c3),
                       c4 = mean(data$c4))
# No random effects variable is needed!

# Calculate Predicitons with stnadard errors, and confidence intervals subsequently

pred.se <- predict(M.avg, type="response", se.fit=TRUE, re.form=NA, full=T, newdata)
  newdata$fit <- pred.se$fit
  newdata$SE <- pred.se$se
  newdata$upr=newdata$fit+1.96*newdata$SE
  newdata$lwr=newdata$fit-1.96*newdata$SE

# full=T defines the use of  full model-averaged coefficients see [here][1] 
# (full=F would not work either, due to mixed models); type= "response" 
# calculates predictions on the response scale (i.e. uses the inverse link
# function, exp() in poisson); re.form = NA avoids the use of random factors
# (inclusion is not possible with se.fit=TRUE).
```

Note: when using glmmadmb(family="nbinom2") the use of type="response" is not possible, but type="link" is. You could take the exp() of fit, SE, lwr, and upr, afterwards in the newdata frame.

The plots can be produced by:

```
p1 <- ggplot(newdata, aes(x=c1, y=fit)) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lwr, ymax = upr), alpha = .25) +
    geom_line(size = 2) +
    labs(x = "c1 continous variable (restandardized)", y = "y response variable on original scale")
  print(p1)
```

Don't foget to re-standadize z transformed predictor variables in the final newdata frame. i.e.:

```
x <- attr(data, 'scaled:scale')
scale <- data.frame(t(x))
x <- attr(data, 'scaled:center')
center <- data.frame(t(x))

newdata$c1 <- newdata$c1 * scale$c1 + center$c1
newdata$c2 <- newdata$c2 * scale$c2 + center$c2
newdata$c3 <- newdata$c3 * scale$c3 + center$c3
newdata$c4 <- newdata$c4 * scale$c4 + center$c4
```

Now I am just wondering, why calculation of confidence intervals from single general linear mixed models (GLMMs) are so intensively discussed. Often you hear that you need [complicated bootstrap methods](http://www.r-bloggers.com/confidence-intervals-for-prediction-in-glmms/) or [MarkovChainMonteCarlo (MCMC)](http://ms.mcmaster.ca/~bolker/R/misc/foxchapter/bolker_chap.html) algorithms to produce confidence intervals. Very, very complex for non-mathematicians. And even the function confint() takes much longer to calculate profile confidence intervals from a single mixed models than does from type=averaging model objects. Probably this is a Question of Accuracy and the se.fit = TRUE method is the least accurate? Furthermore i don't know if [a correction method](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205803/using-information-theory-with-all-possible-models-to-select-the-best-model) for Confidence intervals is included in the procedure presented here.

Comment: I am currently doing some research on this very topic. And I came across some ressources stating that the here-mentioned approach is not correct. See for example https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2018/12/10/confidence-intervals-for-glms/, where Gavin Simpson explains that doing these calculations on the response scale is wrong (and if I understand it right, this exactly what it is presented in this answer). Unfortunatly, I cannot point towards a better solution - I am still in search by myself.